# Fade out volume on pause for mediaelementJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio, fade, mediaelement.js

What is the best way to fade out volume on pause for mediaelementJS player?

It works fine to set **media.volume = 0.0**, and then use jQuery to animate the volume up for play listener. But for the pause listener, audio is paused before I get any chance to fade the audio out.

```
var volumeSet = 0.8; //Default volume
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('video,audio',{

   success: function (media, domObject) {

       //This works fine 
       media.addEventListener('play', function() {

            media.volume = 0;
            $('video,audio').animate({volume: volumeSet}, 1000, "swing");

        }, false)

       //This 'works', but lags as its needed to be re-played after pause 
       media.addEventListener('pause', function(e) {

            if (media.volume>0) {

                volumeSet = media.volume;
                media.play();

                $('video,audio').animate({volume: 0.0}, 1000, "swing", function(){
                    media.pause();
                });

            }

        }, false);

    }

});
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm working on something similar right now... :-)

Comment: Sorry, I'm now using [jplayer](http://jplayer.org/) instead, but actually I skipped this functionality :/ Anyways I recomend jPlayer where it should be a bit easier.